# iTunes does not have ibooks option

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, ipad, books

I recently bought mac book air. In that I have itunes 11.2.1 version. Now I want to move all of my contents from my previous mac book's itunes to this new one and completely sync both my ipad and iphone with new mac book. But the problem is that I don't even have any option to selection ibooks from new itune 11.2.1. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

When I want to add ibooks there from preferences there also does not have the option to add ibook. Below is the screenshot of preferences

[image]

**How can I add ibooks so that I could sync my books with my ipad?**

Answer (score 1):

iBooks has moved to the iBooks app - you should have seen this splash screen the first time you opened the Books tab...

*BTW, the current iTunes is 11.4*

[image]

You sync the same way as before, from iTunes...

[image]

Comment: how can I sync my ipad with ibook app?